# Qt: QAudioInput vs QAudioRecorder

Tags: c++, qt, qtmultimedia, qaudiorecorder, qaudioinput

I am using Qt Multimedia 5 to analyze audio (FFT, LUFS, and dBFS, etc.) from audio input device.
To get audio data, there are two main options, [QAudioRecorder](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudiorecorder.html) and [QAudioInput](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudioinput.html).
They can all read audio data with PCM (QAudioInput use QBuffer and QAudioRecorder use QAudioBuffer) and set format (e.g., sample rate), what should I use? I want to know the difference between QAudioRecorder and QAudioInput.

Comment: Is this about Qt 5 or Qt 6? Add relevant version tags please. The multimedia interface has been cleaned up in Qt 6 so the differences are important.

Comment: Qt 5. Modified in the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QAudioBuffer` is very convenient, and you'd use the `QAudioProbe` class to get notified whenever a new buffer is available - in Qt 5. `QAudioProbe` is not supported on Mac OS unfortunately.

`QAudioProbe` doesn't exist in Qt 6, and wasn't fully supported in Qt 5 either.

The only way to access "live" raw audio data in both Qt 5 and Qt 6 with minimal latency is by making your own `QIODevice` and being fed data from `QAudioSource` in *push* mode - see the [Audio Source example](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qtmultimedia-multimedia-audiosource-example.html), specifically the [`AudioInfo` class](https://github.com/qt/qtmultimedia/blob/dev/examples/multimedia/audiosource/audiosource.h).

The process is as follows:

1. Create an instance of your io device.
2. Pass it to `QAudioSource::start(QIODevice*)`. The audio source will be writing raw data to the device you provided.
3. In the device's implementation, you can either work on the data directly, or synthesize a `QAudioBuffer` instance and send it out in a signal.

Something like the following would work:

```
class AudioProbeDevice : public QIODevice
{
   Q_OBJECT
   QAudioFormat m_format;
public:
   AudioProbeDevice (QObject* parent = {}) : QIODevice(parent) {}
   void start(QAudioInput *source)
   {
      Q_ASSERT(source);
      m_format = source->format();     
      open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
   }
   qint64 readData(char *, qint64) override { return 0; }
   qint64 writeData(const char *data, qint64 count) override
   {
      QAudioBuffer buffer({data, static_cast<int>(count)}, m_format);
      emit audioAvailable(buffer);
      return count;
   }
   Q_SIGNAL void audioAvailable(const QAudioBuffer &buffer);
};
```

Comment: Any info about QAudioRecorder and QAudioInput?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner ??? It's basically "trust the source, Luke" at the moment. The multimedia module is in flux, and the design overall is just weird, so I'm not even sure it's worth using it anymore. There are better audio frameworks out there, much easier to use. That's one side of Qt that got underfunded I'd say, and it's been that way over a decade.